# How to set title for android notification, using alarm manager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am setting an alarm using an AlarmManager.

The AlarmManager is set with the date that i parse.

I have a getter and setter class that i use to pull the release dates and the name of the items when the list is populated.

How could i go about setting the title of the item when the alarm goes off as a notification?

EDIT:   I would like to set a title with the alarm date. I dont know if this is possible.

What i am trying to do is launch a notification with the alarm manager. But i dont know how  would identify which item is is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to display in the title of the notification just pass that string to the `"Ticker"` variable in the following code..

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, Ticker, when);
```

or follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) example

Comment: how would I go about setting a click listener with an intent that launches an activity and passes a url string?